# How to connect to Oracle Docker image

Tags: oracle, docker

I am fairly new to Docker and Oracle Docker image. I need sone help please.

I created docker image for Oracle 12c EE as per Github instructions (https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase)
The image created OK but I could not work out  way to connect to the DB either via command line or via Oracle EM?

Oracle Enterprise Manager ask for username/password and container name. I assume user name will be pdbadmin with default auto generated password during container creation and container name which was also created during "docker run --name".

any suggestion what I should try?

Comment: what did you try? the instructions say

Once the container has been started and the database created you can connect to it just like to any other database:

sqlplus sys/<your password>@//localhost:1521/<your SID> as sysdba
sqlplus system/<your password>@//localhost:1521/<your SID>
sqlplus pdbadmin/<your password>@//localhost:1521/<Your PDB name>
The Oracle Database inside the container also has Oracle Enterprise Manager Express configured. To access OEM Express, start your browser and follow the URL:

https://localhost:5500/em/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to docker Oracle instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554498/how-do-i-connect-to-docker-oracle-instance)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be explicit with the address your sqlplus connection command, as thatjeffsmith pointed out in his comment on your question.

Assuming you start the container by mapping port `1521`, and that `oracle` is the default password, you connect to oracle inside the container like so:

```
sqlplus sys/oracle@//localhost:1521/xe as sysdba
```